# array.sort(function(a, b) {return b.value - a.value) not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I want to retrieve data from firebase and sort them according to the field 'overallScore' in descending order. I have seen other posts on using array.sort(function(a, b) {return b.value - a.value) but this line of code failed to sort the array for me and I don't know why.

My firebase data structure looks like:

[image]

and my code look like:

```
    getAll: function(){
      database.collection('Users').get().then(querySnapShot => {
        let data = [];
        querySnapShot.forEach(doc => { 
            data.push(doc.data())
        })
        this.datasets = data;
        this.getTop();
      })
    },
    getTop: function(){
      var today = String(moment(String(new Date())).format("DDMMYYYY"));
      var top = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.datasets.length; i++) {
        if (this.datasets[i].scoreDate == today){
          top.push(this.datasets[i]);
        }
      }
      top.sort(function(a, b){return b.overallScore - a.overallScore});
      this.top10 = top;
    },
```

This is the console log result after for(...):

[image]

Comment: can you console log `top` variable after for (... ) ?

Comment: If you have seen other posts with `return b.value - a.value`, why are you not using that?

Comment: Can you plese paste the result of JSON.stringify(top) before the sort() on it is called? And you should return numeric value (-1, 0 or 1) from the comparator function. It's not like filter() for example where true or false is used to pick or reject element.

Comment: Please define "*it's not working*". Also, what values exactly do the `.overallScore`s have?

Comment: Hi all, I have updated my question according to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

[sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method return value has 3 options: 1, -1, 0

```
top.sort(function (a, b) { return a.overallScore > b.overallScore ? 1 : a.overallScore < b.overallScore ? -1 : 0 });
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but it's still not working :(

Comment: can you populate the overall score value in top array?

Comment: updated the screenshot

Comment: so, what is your purpose? bigger value first?

Comment: Yes and I realized that my code up there is wrong so I tried b.overallScore - a.overallScore but the array is still not sorted.

Comment: did you console `top` after sort?

Comment: It's the last screenshot I shared above

Answer (score 0):

change sort function to
a.overallScore - b.overallScore

```
let top = [
  {overallScore: 1},
  {overallScore: 2},
    {overallScore: 8},
  {overallScore: 12},
    {overallScore: 4},
  {overallScore: 5},
    {overallScore: 3},
  {overallScore: 29},
]

top.sort(function(a, b)
         {
          return (a.overallScore - b.overallScore);}
        );

console.log(top)
```

https://jsbin.com/zofogar/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for answering but it still didn't work :(

Comment: what does it mean "didn't work"?
Copy your array to jsbin and run my code.

What is result array after sorting?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It means the array is still not sorted

Comment: also, please display "top" before sorting
maybe this condition is not correct? date formats may be different.

Is there any reason why you use 'var' and not 'let' (or better 'const' for 'today')

 if (this.datasets[i].scoreDate == today)

Comment: I don't think comparing the date is the problem here. I have also updated the screenshot of console log after for(...).

Comment: the problem is with sorting function. It should return 0, >0 or <0

Your function returns true or false.